# How to change the color range of data points in ggplot2 geom_jitter()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having fun exploring R and ggplot2. I am now having a problem to change the gradient of my data points when using ggplot2 and geom_jitter. Here is the code I am using:

```
t1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl),y=mpg))
t2 <- geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA)
t3 <- geom_jitter(width=0.3, size=3, aes(color = disp))
t1 + t2 + t3
```

returns:
[image]

However, I would like the higher number to be dark. Or even better - I would like to have the highest numbers in red and the lowest numbers in green (just an example).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works :

```
t1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl),y=mpg))
t2 <- geom_boxplot(outlier.shape=NA)
t3 <- geom_jitter(width=0.3, size=3, aes(color = disp))
t4 <- scale_colour_gradient(low="green",high="red") 
t1 + t2 + t3 + t4
```

Comment: Just one more question: why did you disp in brackets? t3 <- geom_jitter(width=0.3, size=3, aes(color = (disp)))

Comment: That is my bad, was converting it to numeric using `as.numeric()` as gradient makes most sense on numeric values

Answer (score 0):

You need to define disp as a categorical variable indicating the order of the variables

```
mtcars$disp = factor(mtcars$disp, levels = names_of_levels_ordered)
```